# How to store the date of user logout?

Tags: php, symfony

I need to know when a user logs out or when his session is timed out.

So far, I manage to store the session when a user is connected with the [PdoSessionHandler](http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/pdo_session_storage.html).

And I also managed to attach an event listener, that listens for the user logout event;

```
class MyListener implements LogoutHandlerInterface {

    public function logout(Request $Request, Response $Response, TokenInterface $Token) 
    {
     // stuff
    }
}
```

So how can I create an event listener for when the session of the user is timed out?